# Create a video from images with open-cv

Tags: python, opencv

This is my code:

```
videowriter = cv2.VideoWriter("output.mp4", -1, 1, (self.width,self.height))
for i in range(len(images)):
     videowriter.write(images[i])
videowriter.release()
```

I got an empty file from this. does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: What does `images` contain?

Comment: please review [ask] and [mre].

Comment: @JeruLuke the images are numpy arrays

Comment: @KAOTU Within `cv2.VideoWriter` the height and width must be set to that of the images in the list